# Squeryl and PGObjects

Tags: postgresql, scala, squeryl

I'm facing a quite difficult to solve problem... I have an existing database that is using a lot of postgresql enum.

Now... I don't really know how to retrieve those fields with postgresql. Does anybody manage to do something like that?

I have tried to retrieve them as String but it didn't work... also it didn't work to get them as Int.

Comment: I'd recommend revising this question. Explain things you've tried and the exact text of error messages you got, not just "didn't work". Show sample code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

In general, enums and other database-specific features can be quite poorly supported by ORMs and query generators.

It can be useful to create an updatable view over the problem tables that converts the enums to their `text` form, so the query generator just sees a `text` column, but the enum is what's stored in the database. You then write your queries against those views.

I increasingly think PgJDBC needs an option that causes enums to be sent and received as String, because so many tools get confused by the enum objects.